# Determining the order of quantified statement after negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm confused about determining the order in which the quantified symbols should appear and where it's appropriate to place such that when negating the original statement. For example my Professor gave the example $$\mbox{Original Statement: }\exists a\in Z \ni \forall b\in Z , (a+b) = 0 \\ \mbox{Negation: } \exists b\in Z\ni \forall a\in Z, (a+b)\neq 0$$

However, if you just negate the original statement you obtain the order: $$\forall a\in Z, \exists b\in Z \ni (a+b)\neq 0$$

Where I just moved the $\ni$ to where it seemed appropriate.

Comment: The negation you attribute to the professor is incorrect.

Comment: You are correct and your professor was not.

Comment: Yikes... Well at least it makes sense now.

Comment: @Bram28 Could you elaborate on why the professor is incorrect? I understand it doesn't follow the order in which we are negating original but it has essentially the same statement (only variable names changed) and the negation of the conclusion, therefore if thinking in terms of a truth table I think it should always have the opposite value of the original statement.

Comment: The universal quantifiers are not commutative.

Comment: @Craig first of all, with quantifiers you can no longer use  truth-tables, as there are infnitely many possible domains to consider. But more importantly, the order of quantifiers matters if they are of a different type. Consider: $\forall x \exists y x<y$, means that for every number there is a greater number (true), but $\exists y \forall x x <y$ means that there is a number greater than all numbers (false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, and your professor is not.

And yes, the order of quantifiers matters if they are of a different type.

Consider: $\forall x \exists y x<y$, means that for every number there is a greater number (true), but $\exists y \forall x x <y$ means that there is a number greater than all numbers (false).